# Database rollback on API response failure

Tags: api-design

A customer of ours is very persistent that they expect this "from any API" (meaning they don't want to pay for the changes). I seem to have trouble finding clear information on this though.

Say we have an API that creates an appointment for a calendar. Server-side everything was successful, data is committed to the database. API tries to send the HTTP 201 (Created) response, but something goes wrong there. Client ignores the response, or connection dropped, ...

They want our API to undo the database changes in that particular situation.

The question is not how to do this, but rather if this is something most APIs do? Is this standard behavior? Or something similar like refusing duplicate create requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficult part of course is to actually know if an API has failed to send the response, and as far as I am concerned with respect to the crux of the question, it is not a usual behavior implemented. If the user willingly inputs the data, you can go ahead and store it. If the response doesn't return properly due to timeouts (you are not responsible for user "ignoring" the response), then the client side code can refresh on failure and load fresh data. And the user can delete inputted data themselves(given you provide an endpoint for that)

Depending on the database, it is possible to make all database changes of an API reversible. For example, with SQL, you use [SQL transactions][1] using `commit`, `rollback` and `savepoints`. There is most likely a similar mechanism available for noSQL.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've personally never ran into an API that did this to my knowledge, but then it's not something I ever took for granted so I didn't specifically look for it.